# Blocked when i run this shell script

Tags: linux, shell

```
#!/bin/bash

SERVERS="master slave1 slave2 slave3"

for SERVER in $SERVERS
do
  expect -c "set timeout -1;
             spawn ssh hadoop@$SERVER;
             expect {
               *(yes/no)* {send -- yes\r;exp_continue}
               *assword:* {send -- hadoop\r;exp_continue}
               *$* {send -- \"echo 'ssss'\r\";exp_continue}
               *$* {send -- exit\r;exp_continue}
               eof {exit;0}
              }";
done
```

when i run this script,it's will be block and killed.
‘SERVER’ is hostname list;
Please help me see why,what's wrong with my code.
ERROR MESSAGE AS BELOW:

```
spawn ssh hadoop@master
./gather_pub_key.sh: line 5:  2695 killed              expect -c "set timeout -1;
             spawn ssh hadoop@$SERVER;
             expect {
               *(yes/no)* {send -- yes\r;exp_continue}
               *assword:* {send -- hadoop\r;exp_continue}
               *$* {send -- \"echo 'ssss'\r\";exp_continue}
               *$* {send -- exit\r;exp_continue}
               eof {exit;0}
              }"
```

Comment: Displaying what $SERVER is inside your for loop might give a clue as to *a* problem with that. Translating the error message to english might help get a better response, too.

Comment: That looks like the message that the shell prints when a process is terminated by SIGKILL. Are you running out of memory?